# how to use SystemBarTint with PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've successfully used the SystemBarTint (https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library for all my views/layouts except for the PreferenceFragment.

I set my preferences like so:

```
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

And the preferences file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Settings">  
    <PreferenceScreen 
       ...
       ...
        >        
        <ListPreference
            ....
          />
```

The first preference page is fine, but once I click into a preferenceScreen, the transparent status bar ignores the color I've set for it.

Another issue is that the listview of preferences shows up behind the ActionBar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code below after settings the statusbar and navigationbar configurations:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        SystemBarTintManager.SystemBarConfig config = tintManager.getConfig();
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setPadding(
                config.getPixelInsetRight(), config.getPixelInsetTop(true),
                config.getPixelInsetRight(), 0);
    }
```